# Fiche matériel ou fiche matérielle

Tags: orthographe

I'm trying to understand which is the correct one, whether we write "une fiche matériel" or "fiche matérielle"

Comment: There is nothing special here; you must apply the usual rule of agreement in genre: "fiche" is feminine so the feminine form of the adjective is required and that is "matérielle"; therefore you must write "fiche matérielle". This must have been treated in some question already.

Answer (score 13):

Both are possible:

1. "fiche matérielle": the word "matériel" is the adjective here, and it agrees. It means then "an actual, material card", as opposed to a virtual one (although I would rather then say "fiche physique" as opposed to "fiche virtuelle" such as an online form or an electronic document, or even "fiche papier"), or even to an imaginary card
2. "fiche matériel": the word "matériel" is the noun here, used as
   apposition and there is therefore no agreement. You can see it as a
   short form for "fiche qui concerne le matériel" or "fiche qui reprend
   la liste du matériel". You can find some similar occurences such as
   "fiche santé" (= fiche qui reprend les informations concernant l'état
   de santé), "fiche sécurité" (= fiche qui reprend les informations
   liées à la sécurité), etc.

Les deux sont possibles :

1. "fiche matérielle" : le mot "matériel" est utilisé comme adjectif et s'accorde. Cela signifie « une fiche réelle, faite de matière » par opposition à une fiche virtuelle (bien que je dirais plutôt alors "une fiche physique" par opposition à une "fiche virtuelle" telle qu'un formulaire en ligne ou un document électronique, ou même par opposition à une fiche imaginaire).
2. "fiche matériel" : le mot "matériel" est utilisé comme nom commun en apposition et il n'y a donc pas d'accord. C'est une sorte de forme abrégée de « fiche qui concerne le matériel » ou « fiche qui reprend la liste du matériel ». On peut trouver des usages similaires comme "fiche santé" (= fiche qui reprend les informations concernant l'état de santé), "fiche sécurité" (= fiche qui reprend les informations liées à la sécurité), etc.

Comment: Je t'upvote. Tu as été plus rapide que moi ;-)

Comment: Pouvez-vous traduire votre réponse, en français s'il vous plait !!

Comment: Volontiers, mais notez que ce SE, si la question est posée en anglais, on répond en général en anglais (la logique étant que si l'OP a posé la question en anglais, c'est qu'il ne maitrise pas encore assez le français pour poser sa question).

Comment: fiche matériel" et nous avons plusieurs fiches à ce moment on dit fiches matériels ?

Comment: Non, "matériel" est alors une apposition et ne s'accorde pas: ce sont des "fiches qui concernent le matériel", on écrira donc "des fiches matériel".

Comment: fiche matériel au pluriels devienra fiches matériel ou fiches matériels ?

Answer (score 5):

Both are possible depending on whether *matériel* is an adjective or a noun in apposition.

As always, the context is key but I believe the second case is much more likely to happen, for example to distinguish *fiche matériel* and *fiche logiciel*.

---

Les deux sont possibles suivant que *matériel* est un adjectif ou un nom en apposition.

Comme toujours, le contexte est primordial mais il me semble que le deuxième cas (apposition) est bien plus courant, par exemple pour distinguer *fiche matériel* et *fiche logiciel*.

Comment: Pouvez-vous traduire votre réponse, en français s'il vous plait !!

Comment: Bien sûr, mais tu as posé la question en anglais...