# "Carte étudiant" or "carte étudiante" ?

Tags: adjectifs, accord

French student cards include the header "Carte étudiant**e**", which I found a bit surprising. Doesn't it imply that the card is the one who is studying? I would have written "Carte étudiant", like a contraction of "carte (d')étudiant".
Can anybody tell/explain which version is correct?

Comment: Hi @user25326 and welcome to French SE. Someone asked a quite similar question in the beginning of the month, and I believe the answers can be applied to your example as well. :) Here it is: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42868/fiche-mat%c3%a9riel-ou-fiche-mat%c3%a9rielle

Comment: "Carte étudiant" exists too and is the normal term in Belgium. The use of "étudiant.e" as the relational adjectif of the nouns "étude" and "étudiant.e" seems really strange to me, I'd have said "carte estudiantine" if that was the intended meaning

Comment: You almost answered yourself, it's une carte étudiant (student ID), for instance you say to a librarian: "Je possède une carte étudiant" aka "I have a student ID".As for `carte étudiante`, étudiante refers to carte which means "a studying card" and that is senseless since cards are not students, but as said in previous  comments, it might be used in some French dialects but it is grammatically and phonetically incorrect when you get used to French.

Comment: I am also puzzled by this usage of "carte étudiante". Is there a possibility that this label "carte étudiant(e)" is printed differently if the owner is a male or female student ? So that male student have a card labeled "carte étudiant" and female students "carte étudiante" ?

Comment: @Greg Well, no, I am a male student and just received my card from Sorbonne Université which indicates "Carte étudiante européenne"